# apt-get works via proxy, but nothing else does

Tags: 14.04, networking, apt, google-chrome, proxy

This pertains to Ubuntu 14.04 behind a proxy server that requires authentication.

I've managed to get apt-get working via proxy. My `/etc/apt/apt.conf` looks like this:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://my_proxy_server:3128/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://my_proxy_server:3128/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://my_proxy_server:3128/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://my_proxy_server:3128/";
```

My environment variables look the same - I have `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `ftp_proxy` and `socks_proxy` set.

I've a bunch of questions:

1. This proxy server needs authentication. I have not specified username and password for apt-get. However, I can still do `apt-get update` and it works just fine. Why?
2. *None* of the other programs work. For example, `pip install` would fail with the message that it can't fetch  https://pypi.python.org/simple

What is the right way to set up proxy?

**Update**

I installed google-chrome-stable and tried to connect to the internet. It asked me for proxy authentication, which I provided. After this step, `wget` and `pip` seem to work fine! This is really strange. I'm guessing there's some configuration that chrome does which allows the other apps to connect as well.

Now, the new question is, how do I configure it as root? for instance, I can do `pip install ...` and it can download the packages just fine, but if I do `sudo pip install ...`, it fails to connect to the pypi website.

Comment: See my post here: http://askubuntu.com/a/707754/476968

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Put the following lines in the file:

```
export http_proxy=http://my_proxy_server:3128/
export https_proxy=https://my_proxy_server:3128/
export ftp_proxy=http://my_proxy_server:3128/
export socks_proxy=socks://my_proxy_server:3128/
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

```
$ sudo -i
# nano /etc/environment
```

Put the following lines in the file

```
http_proxy=http://my_proxy_server:3128/
https_proxy=https://my_proxy_server:3128/
ftp_proxy=http://my_proxy_server:3128/
socks_proxy=socks://my_proxy_server:3128/
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Comment: I already have this set.